High VRAM usage after loading peft weights with the base model
I have fine-tuned llama-3 using qlora technique and wanted to do inference.
I use the below code for inference.
bnb_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(
    load_in_4bit= True,
    bnb_4bit_quant_type= "nf4",
    bnb_4bit_compute_dtype= torch.bfloat16,
    bnb_4bit_use_double_quant= False)

access_token = ''

base_model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    base_model_id,    quantization_config = bnb_config,
    device_map="auto",    #use_auth_token=True/
    token = access_token
    )

peft_model = PeftModel.from_pretrained(base_model, path)

When I load the base model in 4-bit precision, the VRAM usage is around 6 GB. However, when I load the PEFT model using the same function, the VRAM usage spikes to 19 GB. During fine-tuning, only 11% of the parameters are trainable.
I'm trying to understand why there's such a large increase in VRAM usage after loading the adapter weights. Could it be because the QLoRA adapter weights are being loaded in 16-bit precision? Is there a way to load these adapter weights in 8-bit?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
